# Permission denied - opening Vimeo inside jquery Horizontal Accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion, vimeo, permission-denied

i'm trying to build a website using a jquery horizontal accordion following this handy tutorial http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jQuery-common-accordion

here's the site i've built (new user so only one hyperlink, sorry) at www.adjustyour.tv/201008

now, each time i click on a header to open another video tab, firefox is giving me the following error -

```
Permission denied for <http://player.vimeo.com> to call method Location.toString on <http://www.adjustyour.tv>.
```

i dont have the first idea what this means (being a novice)... any help would be gladly appreciated. please let me know if i need to supply any more details

### update

thanks to mkoistinen who pointed out i forgot any type of code, i've upload a little zip folder - i would just put a snippet of code, but i don't know what snippet would be needed

www.adjustyour.tv/201008/website_code.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are embedding a vimeo player using their iframe embed code, this error is coming from the Vimeo javascript code within the iframe. See http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:28447#comment_3658475 for their comment on this - in short you'll have to live with it until they rewrite their embed code!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the old embed method provided here http://www.miracletutorials.com/howto-embed-vimeo/. It's just using the embed object with no iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, cool design concept!

Secondly, you haven't really posted any code here, but I wonder if you're passing document.location somewhere and it wants document.location.href?  Just a wild guess.  Good luck!

Comment: cheers for getting back to me so quickly, and thanks for the design flattery... if i had any idea what section of code to show you, i would... so i've put up a link to all the code - though i fully understand if you dont have the time to trawl all of it.